# How to check-in on Foursquare without a mobile device?

Tags: foursquare

Foursquare allows you to check-in from mobile devices via it's app for different devices. Is there a way to check-in from your PC?

Comment: Check-ins have been removed from Foursquare and moved to the new [Swarm](http://swarmapp.com) app, which does not have a Web interface.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check-in from your PC as well using http://m.foursquare.com
I don't know if it checks the IP address to see if the location is within reach or not.

Also, TweetDeck has provided support for Foursquare and the desktop version of the software allows you to update your location from desktop.

Comment: It doesn't check the IP address for location, but none of the check-ins on the mobile site will count towards mayorships (only check-ins from GPS-capable mobile clients count).

Comment: I'm not sure about now but back then I did acquired quite a few mayorships with this method.

Comment: Yeah, that's why they changed it, too many people were cheating and checking in at places they weren't physically located at.

Comment: This is no longer true, since check-ins have been removed from Foursquare.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can't check in without a mobile device. All you can do is change your current location. Just login to the Foursquare site and change your current location.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used either of them, but have you tried either [Foursquare for Firefox](http://www.foursquarefox.com/) or logging in on the [Foursquare mobile web site](http://foursquare.com/mobile/login?continue=%2Fmobile%2F) and setting your location there?

Answer (score -1):

It was possible until a couple of months ago. I just tried to log in by using foursquare.com/mobile/login page, however it does not work anymore. Link redirects you to foursquare.com/download